# How use target for one Xcode project in other projects?

Tags: xcode, target

I have an example project that I made to test a target that allows me compile OpenGL and FreeGLUT code on my Mac. I followed the example here :

http://blog.onesadcookie.com/2007/12/xcodeglut-tutorial.html

I am trying to make a new project, and it also will need OpenGL and FreeGLUT.

How do I save/export the target from the first project to the second?

I am sorry if this is a newbie question, I am new to Xcode development.